# No se me guardan las imagenes en php tras subirla en servidor

Tags: php, imagen, archivo, fileupload

Acabo de subir mi proyecto en un servidor de mi universidad e intento subir una publicación con una imagen y se guarda todo ok en la BD, pero no se me guarda en la carpeta del proyecto el archivo de imagen.

En local me funciona bien :c. Este es mi código para almacenar, creo que debe ser por el tema de la ruta del servidor, pero no sé que cambiar en ese caso.

```
<?php 
include("conexion.php");

if(isset($_POST['publicar'])){

     if(!empty($_POST['titulo']) && !empty($_POST['contenido']) ){

        $titulo = $_POST['titulo'];
        $contenido = $_POST['contenido'];
        $rut_user = $_SESSION['id_user'];

        // Recibo los datos de la imagen
         $nombre_img = $_FILES['imagen']['name'];
         $tipo = $_FILES['imagen']['type'];
         $tamano = $_FILES['imagen']['size'];

         //Si existe imagen y tiene un tamaño correcto
         if ($nombre_img == !NULL)
         {
         //indicamos los formatos que permitimos subir a nuestro servidor
         if (($_FILES["imagen"]["type"] == "image/gif")
         || ($_FILES["imagen"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
         || ($_FILES["imagen"]["type"] == "image/jpg")
         || ($_FILES["imagen"]["type"] == "image/png"))
         {
         // Ruta donde se guardarán las imágenes que subamos
         $path= '../img/uploads/';
         $imgPath=$path.$_FILES['imagen']['name'];
         $directorio = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/img/uploads/';
        
         // Muevo la imagen desde el directorio temporal a nuestra ruta indicada anteriormente
         move_uploaded_file($_FILES['imagen']['tmp_name'],$imgPath);
         }
         else
         {
            //si no cumple con el formato
            echo "No se puede subir una imagen con ese formato ";
         }
         }
         else
         {
         //si existe la variable pero se pasa del tamaño permitido
         if($nombre_img == !NULL) echo "La imagen es demasiado grande ";
         }
        //Sacar fecha actual
        date_default_timezone_set("America/Santiago");
        $fecha = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', time());
        //valor fecha para comparar
        $valor_fecha = strtotime($fecha);
        $estado_entrega = 1;
        $estado_producto = 1;
        $query = "INSERT INTO posts(titulo,contenido,imagen,fecha,rut_user,id_estado,id_entrega) VALUES('$titulo','$contenido','$nombre_img','$fecha','$rut_user',1,1)";
        $agregar = mysqli_query($conexion,$query);
        if($agregar==false){
            echo $query.'<br>';
            echo "Error al agregar: ".mysqli_error($conexion);
        }else{
           header("location: ../index.php");
        }
        }else{
        echo "Campos vacios o incompletos!";
     }
}
?>
```

esta es la estructura de mi servidor
[image: proyecto en servidor]

Comment: Revisa que la variable `$path` realmente apunte a la ruta que corresponde, aunque parece más adecuado lo que hiciste con `$directorio`, pero no la estás usando. También revisa que la carpeta tiene permisos de escritura.

Answer (score 0):

creo que te falta abrir la ruta con opendir y modificar el move_uploaded y el $directorio

```
 $path= '../img/uploads/';
         $imgPath=$path.$_FILES['imagen']['name'];
         $directorio = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].$imgPath;
         $dir = opendir($directorio);
         move_uploaded_file($_FILES['imagen']['tmp_name'],$directorio); //recuerda que la ruta a colocar es la del servidor
         closedir($dir);
```